# Remove one Array elements from another Array Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, logic

I have an array A and another array B. How do I remove elements in A from B and what would be the running time of the algorithm? Duplicates allowed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How to remove is implementation-dependent.  You haven't even specified a language for the implementation; at the algorithm level, it's merely the set `B-A`.  The running time depends on the hardware, the language, the implementation of an array, the hardware you're running on, array sizes ...

Comment: Which algorithm do you intend to use? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

A single array has a worst-case running time of O(N) and two arrays will typically have an array running time of O(N^2). You can use a system event or user input to remove an element, e.g. for a string array you may ask the user select the elements they want to remove and assign an empty string in those indices or you can use a system event to remove the required elements.

Answer (score 0):

The running time totally depends on your implementation.

Sort A and the running time could be O((A + B) log A).

If the values in A and B can be hashed, the running time could be O(A + B)

If you don't care about the array elements maintaining their relative order, removing an item is O(1). Just swap the item you want to remove with the last item and decrement your size.

Comment: It is possible to maintain elements order with the same complexity - just miss duplicates (counting them) and move good element from i-th position into `A[i - dupcount]`